# Submitting rails a remote true form_for and no redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am really new in web development. I just started some weeks ago reading the ruby on rails tutorial and before it I only knew a bit of C+. So the question is probably easy for you but I have already spent 2 days looking for an answer which I didn't find. 
What I have is a form_for with a data field which appear/disappear depending on the radio button clicked. This works fine, when I submit the form the data are saved in the database correctly! The problem is that I am not redirected at all. In the shell it is written

**render patient/show.html.erb within layouts/application  Completed 200 ok**

BUT in the browser I still see the /srtinitial_infos/new (ie the page where I fill in the form).

**My code is**

```
   #new.html.erb
<%= form_for(:srtinitial_infos, url: {action: "create"},remote: true) do |f|%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "srtinitial_infos_new.js" %>
 <p>
    <strong>Operations  </strong>
<%= f.radio_button :operation, '1', :value=>1%>
<%=label   :operation_yes,'Yes'%>
<%= f.radio_button   :operation, '0', :value=>0%>
<%=label   :operation_no,'No'%>
<%= f.radio_button   :operation, '2', :value=>2%>
<%=label   :operation_ni,'No info'%>
</p>    

<div id="opdate">
<p>
<strong>Date of operation  </strong>
<%=f.date_select :operationdate%><br>
<p>
</div>
<p>
<strong>Date of MRI  </strong>
<%=f.date_select :mridate%><br>
<p>


<%=f.submit "Save" %>
```

The Javascript

```
 #javascript/srtinitial_infos_new.js.erb
 $(function(){

$("#opdate").hide();

$("input:radio[name='srtinitial_infos[operation]']").change(function(){  

        if(this.value == 1 && this.checked){
          $("#opdate").show();
        }else{
          $("#opdate").hide();
        }

    });

  });
```

The controller

```
def create
  @patient=Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
if @patient.srtinitial_info
 render 'show'
else
@srtinitial_info=@patient.create_srtinitial_info(srtinitial_infos_params)
 @srtinitial_info.author=@current_user.email
 @srtinitial_info.save
 redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
 end
end
```

Since I think that the problem is in the controller since data are saved correctly, I also try to write stuff like

```
   def create
@patient=Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
@srtinitial_info=@patient.create_srtinitial_info(srtinitial_infos_params)
@srtinitial_info.author=@current_user.email
respond_to do |format|
    if @patient.srtinitial_info
     format.html { render action: "show"}
    else @srtinitial_info.save
     format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Correctly initialized.'}
     format.js   {}
    end
```

I tried similar stuff in the new controller

```
 def new
  @patient=Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb  
    format.js
  end
 end
```

If I do not use the remote: true everything works well (apart the hide/show option obviously)
I hope that the question is clear :)
Cheers

Comment: The purpose of `remote: true` is that it won't redirect you, this is Ruby's unobtrusive javascript way of creating an AJAX form instead of a standard form. In this case your server is saying it's rendering the show because it is, that's how it's responding to the AJAX request. I'm not sure why your hide/shows would not be working without `remote: true` however.

Comment: When you do `remote: true`, it becomes a ajax request and the block for `format.html` will never be executed.

Comment: @Clark you are right! Actually the_remote: true_ is useless in my case. In one of my versions it was useful but in this one it is not. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.js.erb` files to respond to AJAX requests. In this case you need `show.js.erb` in the same views folder as `show.html.erb`. The file uses javascript to update the page without a refresh/redirect.

Assuming you have a div with id `notice` where you want to display the message, your `show.js.erb` might just look like this:

```
$("#notice").html("<%= flash [:notice] %>"):
```

If you want to redirect to another page, then you could do a client-side redirect from the controller:

```
window.location = "<%= patient_path @user %>";
```